Getting centroids of a shape that align with NLDAS resolution in GEE
I have a shapefile of a watershed that I need to get NLDAS forcing data for. I want to get the centroids for the parts of the watershed within each NLDAS pixel in Google Earth Engine. I know there's the 'polygon.centroid()' command but I'm not exactly sure how to use it to get multiple centroids.
For example, I don't want a single centroid of the shapefile, but the centroid for each part of the watershed within the 1/12 degree grid from NLDAS. And then pull the information for each of those centroids. Any ideas?

It's not totally clear how to answer this without a working example. One way to obtain the centroids can be by getting the indented grid over the watershed boundaries as a feature collection and map the .centroid() function over this feature collection. However, if your end goal is to extract the pixel information, in practice what you want as "the centroid for each part of the watershed within the 1/12 degree grid from NLDAS"  is the pixel grid that is totally within the watershed boundary, so all you need is to extract at the pixel centroids. In this case, you can use .sample(), which sample the pixels of an image.
Here is a working example of both approaches.
Finally to deal with boundaries pixels, you can intersect the grid to the exact watershed boundaries or use reduceRegion, but as shown in the example I provided in the code. So having the exact centroid would not matter for extracting the NLDAS information because the grid centroid and the exact intersection centroid, although not matching, they will overlap the same NLDAS pixel! A better way to account for this is to extract the value of the pixel weighted by the fraction of the pixel area intersected with the watershed. Reducer will do this. But this is a separate discussion about the assumptions that makes sense to your purpose and data
